# Remote debug DotNetNuke (DNN) module on azure wesbite

Tags: c#, asp.net, dotnetnuke, remote-debugging

I created a DNN website on azure from the gallery on azure. I then created a custom module using aspnet/C# within VS2013. I was able to properly build this and deploy the files (using FTP) to my DNN on azure and add the module to a page.

So currently my custom DNN module works ok on my azure DNN website. The question now is there anyway to remotely debug this custom module in visual studio that sits on my azure DNN site? I installed the azure SDK and did as the steps say to remotely debug a website by right clicking the website and clicking "Attach Debugger" however none of my breakpoints in my custom module seem to be getting hit.

Is there anything I may be missing so I can accomplish this? I would like to bypass if possible the need to locally install DNN.

Comment: how did you setup your module dev environment? Did you use FTP to map to the DesktopModule of your Azure install or did you install a local version of DNN. Thanks

Comment: I used this DNN module template VSIX (a bit outdated) a while back http://www.subodh.com/Blog/PostID/90/Dotnetnuke-Module-Development-template-for-VS2010 and then just have carried that project structure forward across the years. Unfortunately it doesn't look as if the creator has updated it to work in newer versions of VS. I also had a local DNN install that when I build the module the post build events would push changes to my local directories so I could test things. When it comes to moving my code out to Azure yes I just used FTP to map to the desktop modules folder.

Answer (score 2):

That normally works (I've been doing it for a while). Ensure that you upload your module assembly built in Debug mode and that the module .pdb is in the \bin folder as well.

Here the proof of concept working: https://twitter.com/davidjrh/status/545753925790756864/photo/1

Comment: Does this work with azure websites. Or do you have to be using a virtual machine?

Comment: Never mind, here is a link that explains how.  http://blogs.msdn.com/b/webdev/archive/2013/11/05/remote-debugging-a-window-azure-web-site-with-visual-studio-2013.aspx  This is really handy +1's all around